# is_open returns true, but getline only returns empty strings

Tags: c++

I am attempting to read from a .csv file in c++. After calling myfile.open(file), is_open returns true, but getline is only returning empty strings.

I have attempted using vectors to read the lines and then writing the vector data to a variable to read, but that has also returned only empty strings.

```
std::ifstream csvFile;
std::string line = "!", temp= "...";

csvFile.open("file.csv");
if(csvFile.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "open\n";
    std::cout << line << "\n";
    if(getline(csvFile, line)) {
        std:: cout << line << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << temp << "\n";
    }
}
else {
    std:: cout << "not opening\n";
}
std:: cout << line;
```

My output is as follows after running.

```
[ctest] open
[ctest] !
[ctest] ...
[ctest]
```

As shown, the getline() return only an empty string, although the file itself is not empty.

These are the first 20 or so lines of the csv file, and I have made sure that the file is in the current working directory.

Alpha002

16:55:54 13/6/2019

428,1.61,-1.31,-0.13,0,0

448,1.61,-1.47,-0.13,0,0

468,1.68,-1.07,-0.44,0,0

488,1.61,-1.39,-0.76,0,0

508,1.61,-1.47,-0.68,0,0

3528,1.61,-1.55,-0.36,0,0

3548,1.61,-1.31,-0.28,0,0

3568,1.68,-1.15,-0.36,0,0

3588,1.68,-1.63,-0.76,0,0

3608,1.68,-0.76,-0.68,0,0

3628,1.68,-1.15,-0.21,0,0

3648,1.68,-0.76,-0.28,0,0

3668,1.68,-1.39,-0.13,0,0

3688,1.68,-1.07,-0.21,0,0

3708,1.61,-1.47,0.03,0,0

I am not sure how to proceed from here, as i cannot find any issues apart from that, any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Given that output, `getline` clearly fails (thus printing `...`). Are you *sure* the file isn't empty?

Comment: Can you please share your csv file?

Comment: `std::` is missing from `getline`

Comment: Unless the first line _is_ `...` of course. Anyway, showing the file - and making certain it is in your current working directory when the program runs - would be helpful.

Comment: just guessing here but is there a chance you have a second file named file.csv in the directory you're executing the code from?

Comment: So, I used your data and created my csv file, and worked just fine. Take a look at this [code](https://gist.github.com/EsdrasXavier/af396273c07bce8e105739e701486176)

Comment: Worked on my machine.  You may want to use `getcwd` to confirm the current working directory is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], that is a full program with `#include` directives and all other little things intact.

Comment: @mrzrm it isn't, `getline` is found through ADL since its arguments are from namespace `std`.

Comment: for testing you could also write the file in the same code. Your code looks fine, so even with a [mcve] I guess it will be difficult to diagnose your problem, from what you write it seems like the file is actually empty

Comment: @EsdrasXavier I tried your code, and it outputs "File opened," then "Failed to read file"... I have included both iostream and fstream.

Comment: @Arik That's pretty weird lol. Could you maybe try with anoter file? Maybe write a txt file, also I forgot to put into my code, you should always close the file with **csvFile.close();**

Comment: this example works on linux compiled with gcc, can you tell us more about your usage conditions, the code is not the problem here... maybe your compiler/standard library has some problems, or maybe there's something else you missed

Comment: The output you're seeing is exactly what I would expect if `file.csv` was empty.  As per an earlier comment by @xception , are you sure you don't have multiple files named `file.csv` in different directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, something is wrong with the file itself I was using. I tried reading from another file using the same methods, and it worked without issues. Thank you to everyone who commented trying to help!

Comment: are you maybe using windows and have the thing about hiding file extensions enabled?

Comment: I was using visual studio code on mac. What had happened was that the first couple times I built the project, new, empty files were created in the build folder, part of my main workspace. After deleting the files I had in the directory, the code was still opening blank files, which led me to search through the folders. I have since deleted the extra files, and wrote the full file path when passing it in to open, to avoid repeat situations like this.